# Reduction of Order Non-homogenous System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

I have to write the following system as a first order system of differential equations

x'''-2x''+4x'-y= sin(t)

y''-2y+x''= cos(t)

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Can you find a solution to the homogenous equations? Start with that. Turn it into a single equation in $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x'''-2x''+4x'-y= \sin(t)\quad (1)$$

$$y''-2y+x''= \cos(t)\quad (2).$$

Let $$x_1=x\quad (3)$$
$$x_2=x'\quad (4)$$
$$x_3=x''\quad (5)$$
$$y_1=y\quad (6)$$
$$y_2=y'\quad (7).$$ 
Then the above system is reduced to a first order system $X'=AX+B(t)$ as follows.
$$(3), (4)\Rightarrow x_1'=x_2$$
$$(4), (5)\Rightarrow x_2'=x_3$$
$$(6), (7)\Rightarrow y_1'=y_2$$
$$(1)\Rightarrow x_3'=2x_3-4x_2+x_4+y_1+\sin t$$
$$(2)\Rightarrow y_2'=-x_3+2y_1+\cos t,$$
where $X=(x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2)^t$ and $B(t)=(0, 0, \sin t, 0, \cos t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Write the system in $u_0=x$, $u_1=x'$, $u_2=x''$ and $u_4=y$, $u_5=y'$ with the additional relations like $u_1'=u_2$,...

Comment: wasn't sure how to properly set that up so would I write u'_2 - 2u_2 +4u_1 - U_4 =sin(t), u'_5 - 2u_4 + u_2 = cos(t) ?

Comment: Yes, that and the additional 3 trivial equations connecting the components.